# server not accepting morethan one client in nio

Tags: java, networking, nio

Am trying to build a chat application.i have a code that sends the data from client to server. when one or more client login(when the client program runs one or more time).server will not accepting the rest of connection other than first connected. 
please help me to resolve this
here is my code:

```
public class Server
{

//Creating non blocking socket

public void non_Socket() throws Exception {

    ServerSocketChannel ssChannel = ServerSocketChannel.open();
    int port = 80;
    int i=0;
    ssChannel.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(port));
    ssChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    while(true)
    {
        SocketChannel sc = ssChannel.accept();`

        if (sc == null) 
        {
            System.out.println("Socket channel is null");
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        }
        else 
        {
            System.out.println("Socket channel is not null");
            System.out.println("Received an incoming connection from " +
                    sc.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress()); 
            new PrintRequest(sc,i).start(); 
            i++;
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String [] abc) throws Exception
{
    new Server().non_Socket();
}
}

class PrintRequest extends Thread {

public  PrintRequest(SocketChannel sc,int i) throws Exception
{
    WritableByteChannel wbc = Channels.newChannel(System.out); 
    ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(1024); // read 1024 bytes 
    int numBytesRead = sc.read(b);

    while (numBytesRead != -1) 
    {
        b.flip();

        while (b.hasRemaining())
        { 
            wbc.write(b);
            System.out.println();
            //System.out.println("Stream  "+i);
            // System.out.println("  KKK   "+b.toString());
        }
        //b.clear();
    }    
}
}
```

Client code:

```
public class Client extends Thread {

public void non_Client_Socket() throws Exception
{
    SocketChannel sChannel = SocketChannel.open();
    sChannel.configureBlocking(false);
    sChannel.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost", 80));
    while (!sChannel.finishConnect())
    {
        System.out.println("Channel is not connected yet");
    }

    System.out.println("Channel is ready to use");

    /* ----------  going to send data to server ------------*/   
    System.out.println("please enter the text");
    BufferedReader stdin=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while(true)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the text");
        String HELLO_REQUEST =stdin.readLine().toString();
        if(HELLO_REQUEST.equalsIgnoreCase("end"))
        {
            break;
        }

        System.out.println("Sending a request to HelloServer");    
        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(HELLO_REQUEST.getBytes());    
        sChannel.write(buffer); 
     }
}
     /* ----------  the data is written to sChannel server
                      will read from this channel  ------------   */

public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception
{
    new Client().non_Client_Socket();
}
}
```

Comment: you've seriously butchered your code when posting it here so I may be wrong but: it looks like your "new PrintRequest(sc,i).start();" is supposed to create a new thread, but it won't. try: "new Thread(new PrintRequest(sc,i)).start();".

Comment: @AlexLynch `PrintRequest` extends `Thread` so your comment is incorrect.

Comment: @EJP I see; he cleaned up his code since I saw it. Regardless, the code of PrintRequest is not being run in its own thread. The code should be in a run() method rather than its constructor or else it will be blocking on the main thread.

Comment: @Alex Actually it should be run in the *same* thread as the selector: this is NIO. The entire thing is wrong. He's posted another question where this is being discussed.

Answer (score 4):

There are numerous issues here.

1. You are putting your `ServerSocketChannel` into non-blocking mode and then calling `accept()` without using a Selector. That means 99.9999% of the time `accept()` will return null, so you are burning CPU cycles. This is pointless. Either accept in blocking mode or use a Selector.
2. You are putting your client `SocketChannel` into non-blocking mode, calling `connect(),` and the calling `finishConnect()` without using a Selector. That means 99% of the time `finishConnect()` will return false, so you are burning CPU cycles. This is pointless. Either connect in blocking mode or use a Selector.
3. You are ignoring the result of `SocketChannel.write()`. You can't do that. It returns information you need to know about.

In short, your code doesn't make much sense.

Comment: yes you are absolutly right i got connection with diffrerent client

Answer (score 3):

I don't have time to look into your code in detail, but some initial observations:

1. When using NIO, I suggest you use `Selector` (as I suggested in [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095507/non-blocking-client-server-chat-application-in-java-using-nio)) instead of one thread per client.
2. Remember to `bind` each client in order to allow the server socket to `accept` new connections.

Comment: @Amith So why are you using NIO? In non-blocking mode, NIO is for *economising* on threads.