# My simple Java NIO client server non-blocking connection does not work

Tags: java, nio

I'm trying to play around with a simple client-server program, eventually aiming to make it a two-way communication. For some reason when I just instantiate the client class to make it connect to the server (without sending any data), it doesn't work, and throws `Unable to establish loopback connection` exception. When I put a `while` loop of reading through `stdin`, it works then. I need to establish a connection first, and then once in a while send a message to the server. How can I fix it?

Client code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;

public class ClientCore {

    SelectionKey selkey;
    Selector sckt_manager ;
    SocketChannel sc;

    public ClientCore() {
        try {
            sc = SocketChannel.open();
            sc.configureBlocking(false);
            sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress(8888));

            // should not proceed until connect is finished
            while (!sc.finishConnect()) {
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (sc != null) {
                try {
                    sc.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    void send(String message) {
        try {
            if (!message.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
                System.out.println("Sending a request to the server ...");
                ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(message.getBytes());
                sc.write(buffer);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ClientCore cl = new ClientCore();
        cl.send("hello");
    }
}
```

Server code:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SelectionKey;
import java.nio.channels.Selector;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel;
import java.nio.channels.spi.SelectorProvider;

public class ServerCore extends Thread {

    SelectionKey selkey = null;
    Selector sckt_manager = null;

    public void run() {
        try {
            coreServer();
        } catch (Exception ej) {
            ej.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void coreServer() {
        try {
            ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
            try {
                ssc.socket().bind(new InetSocketAddress(8888));

                while (true) {

                    sckt_manager = SelectorProvider.provider().openSelector();
                    ssc.configureBlocking(false);
                    SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
                    register_server(ssc, SelectionKey.OP_ACCEPT);
                    if (sc == null) {
                    } else {

                        System.out
                                .println("Received an incoming connection from "
                                        + sc.socket().getRemoteSocketAddress());
                        printRequest(sc);
                        System.err.println("testing 1");
                        String HELLO_REPLY = "Sample Display";
                        ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(HELLO_REPLY .getBytes());
                        System.err.println("testing 2");
                        sc.write(buffer);
                        System.err.println("testing 3");
                        sc.close();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (ssc != null) {
                    try {
                        ssc.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception E) {
            System.out.println("Ex in servCORE   " + E);
        }
    }

    private static void printRequest(SocketChannel sc) throws IOException {

        ReadableByteChannel rbc = Channels.newChannel(sc.socket()
                .getInputStream());
        WritableByteChannel wbc = Channels.newChannel(System.out);
        ByteBuffer b = ByteBuffer.allocate(1024); // read 1024 bytes
        while (rbc.read(b) != -1) {
            b.flip();
            while (b.hasRemaining()) {
                wbc.write(b);
                System.out.println();
            }
            b.clear();
        }
    }

    public void register_server(ServerSocketChannel ssc, int selectionkey_ops)
            throws Exception {
        ssc.register(sckt_manager, selectionkey_ops);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerCore st = new ServerCore();
        st.coreServer();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not asynchronous code. It is non-blocking code. Your connect code is entirely equivalent to doing the connect before setting non-blocking mode, except that the latter doesn't smoke the CPU. You don't need a new selector every time around the loop, or to keep setting the `ServerSocketChannel` into non-blocking mode: and as you aren't using the selector it is difficult to understand why you're using one at all. This code doesn't make much sense. Have you studied the Oracle NIO tutorial?

Comment: I followed an example code from a Stackoverflow post: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11095507 It worked as long as we have a loop reading from stdin, and when the loop is separately located in another function, it doesn't work!

Comment: If we should modify it intensively, let me put another code I've tried. How can I make it asynchronous?

Comment: I don't know why on earth you would copy code from questions. You should be copying it from *answers.* It is drivel, and it was answered by referring the OP elsewhere. I can only do the same. You would make it asynchronous by throwing it all away and using `AsynchronousSocketChannel` and friends, but why? What is your actual objective?

Comment: Sorry for that. I'm trying to create a simple two-way communication. It can not be synchronous/ busy-wait. It needs to be asynchronous, with each side polling messages from a queue.

Comment: 'Each side polling messages from a queue' *is* busy-wait. You're conflating four different things here: (1) busy-wait; (2) blocking I/O, (3) non-blocking I/O; (4) asynchronous I/O. No two of these is the same, except that you can implement (2) via (1).

Comment: I see. I will have another post with a new example code.